# Center stat_summary mean for different number of factor levels with position_dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue with the correct dodging of `stat_summary` together with `position_dodge`. I will use the `diamond` data to illustrate. The goal is to visualize how a variable used for prediction (here we use `price`) is distributed among the classes I want to predict (`carat > 1` and `carat < 1`)

Therefore, I binned the continuous `carat` values into two classes `carat > 1` and `carat < 1`.
The average price is calculated for both classes. In an additional step, `carat`
is binned again within the `ggplot2` call for the fill asthetics. The first fill-bin `0-1` goes together with the class `carat < 1`. In my actual data, the first class would be "absent" and the second
class is "present". Therefore, the other fill-bins belong to class `carat > 1` and allow for more detailed display of distribution.

[image: diamonds plot]

My question: is it possible to center the mean `geom_point` for each class, regardless of the number of fill-bins? In this case, the blue-coloured dot should be in the center of the blue circled column and the red-coloured dot should be centered for the present amount of fill-bins (2 or 3).

If been playing around with values for `stat_summary(position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)`
but I just don't get there completely.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
set.seed(10)
diamond_subset <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1500),]
diamond_subset$carat[diamond_subset$carat < 1] <- 0

# plot price of diamond by class label and carat intervals

# split carat values into 2 classes for classification
diamond_subset$classes <- cut(diamond_subset[["carat"]], 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 1, Inf), labels = c("carat_below_1", "carat_above_1")) 

# set intervals for continuous carat values, all intervals > 1 belong to class "carat_above_1"
break_points <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5.1)

ggplot(diamond_subset, aes(x = cut, y = price, colour = classes)) +  
  geom_point(aes(fill = cut(carat, break_points, include.lowest = TRUE)), pch = 21, alpha = 0.4, size = 2,
    position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.7, jitter.width = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(position=position_dodge(width = 0.9), fill = "black", 
    fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "green", "yellow", "red", "black"),
    name = "Carat") +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("blue", "red"),
    name = "Average price per class",
    breaks = c("carat_below_1", "carat_above_1"),
    labels = c("Carat < 1", "Carat > 1")
)
```

Extra question: Is a possible solution also applicable for more than 2 classes? E.g.

```r
diamond_subset$classes <- cut(diamond_subset[["carat"]], 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 2, Inf), labels = c("carat_below_1", "carat_above_1", "carat_above_2")) 

ggplot(diamond_subset, aes(x = cut, y = price, colour = classes)) +  
  geom_point(aes(fill = cut(carat, break_points, include.lowest = TRUE)), pch = 21, alpha = 0.4, size = 2,
    position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.7, jitter.width = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(position=position_dodge(width = 0.9), fill = "black", 
    fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "green", "yellow", "red", "black"),
    name = "Carat") +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("blue", "red", "black"),
    name = "Average price per class",
    breaks = c("carat_below_1", "carat_above_1", "carat_above_2"),
    labels = c("Carat < 1", "Carat > 1", "Carat > 2")
)
```

EDIT:

I can save the plots as pdf and center the dots manually of course, if no one has a solution to this?